# Rails route change controller for index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model `Comment` that belongs to both `Image` and `Video`. My `routes.rb` has

```
resources :images do
    resources :comments
end

resources :videos do
    resources :comments
end
```

Both endpoints hits `comments_controller#index` which is a problem. Is there a way I can get them to hit different functions for the controller such as `comments_controller#image_index` and `comments_controller#video_index`. I prefer not do to do the hacky

```
get 'images/:id/comments' => 'controller#image_index'
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Yes there are ways, but why is it a problem?

Comment: well for simplicity I have a lot of other things in the routes.rb that come after `resources :videos do `... so including the `get` configuration in there would be bad code design.

Comment: So also for code design, I prefer to have different `index` functions in the controllers to represent either model.

Comment: Do they have to hit different methods, or can they be handled differently within the same method?

Comment: preferably with different methods :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't think of a better way yet, but this would work

```
resources :images do
  resources :comments, except: :index do
    collection do
      get '/', to: :images_index
    end
  end
end

resources :videos do
    resources :comments
end
```

Comment: Thanks it works! the `except: :index` seemed redundant, at least on rails 4.2.

Comment: why do you say so? I removed index so it doesn't conflict with the `/` i defined inside

Comment: I just tested it, the custom action and the index both appeared, but the custom action was first, I'll test to see which one is matched in a request